# Installing Ubuntu Studio

Tags: installation, ubuntu-studio

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Studio via USB stick. I follow all the instructions and the USB drive says Ubuntu Studio, but Ubuntu Desktop without the studio installs.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an Ubuntu Desktop installation to Ubuntu Studio by installing the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-video ubuntustudio-graphics linux-lowlatency
```

More information is available in the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation).

Comment: Does this mean that there is no Ubuntu Studio to download at this time. Is the only way to have studio to build it on a Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 first.. Then "upgrade to ubuntu studio after that. I Did this on an Samsung P7 SSD USB drive as "persistent storage" and it works fine.

Have a decent setup with wine and FL Syduio as well working on the Ubuntu system so it is quite "doable".

I Did try to setup Ubuntu studio as persistent storage but for some reason it will not work..Så i recommend the way of installing a "fresh" ubuntu install first..

Answer (score -1):

There are Ubuntu Studio ISO's to download on http://ubuntustudio.org/download/ , both 13.04 and 12.04 LTS.