# Convert Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS to Ubuntu Studio

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-studio

I have been using Ubuntu Studio for a number of years on old laptops and have always installed it via USB. However, I have splashed out on a purpose built Ubuntu Laptop and 20.04.2LTS came pre-installed.

My query is, is there an easy way to "convert" the installation to Ubuntu Studio?

I found this [Installing Ubuntu Studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160908/installing-ubuntu-studio) but its 7 years old and i don't really want to break anything.

Thanks
Ed

Answer (score 3):

The process of Ubuntu Studio installation is straight-forward.
You need to install relevant main task-package by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop^
```

If you know your own creativity area, then install more tasks:

| Task Package | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `ubuntustudio-audio^` | Audio recording and editing suite |
| `ubuntustudio-fonts^` | Large selection of font packages |
| `ubuntustudio-graphics^` | 2D/3D creation and editing suite |
| `ubuntustudio-photography^` | Photograph touchup and editing suite |
| `ubuntustudio-publishing^` | Publishing applications |
| `ubuntustudio-video^` | Video creation and editing suite |

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: So (thank you, and) after installing these && reboot, my LUKS prompt says `Ubuntu Studio` but everything else still says `Ubuntu` ... odd state! Any suggestions to update the logos in Gnome?

Comment: I figured it out: If you want the `ubuntustudio` branding, you must select KDE. That was fun, but I'm back on Gnome with my `ubuntu` vanilla branding now. (:

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose the package [ubuntustudio-installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) exists:

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer
```

and run the installer.