# Can I run Ubuntu Studio on a Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-studio

My question is pretty straight forward Can a Raspberry pi 400 run on Ubuntu Studio? If possible then How?

Comment: I had a look and the installer for *focal* in the Ubuntu Studio PPA was only built for *amd64* - https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+sourcepub/11443481/+listing-archive-extra  which confirms @Artur Meinild's answer/opinion.   (I don't think it relates to the *low-latency* kernel myself as I've read blogs from Ubuntu Studio themselves on why you don't always want to use that kernel & it's not their recommended kernel in many environments - but they do aim at serious creators more than hobbyists).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS to Ubuntu Studio](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339086/66509) ← try installation by using meta-packages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe Ubuntu Studio is by default available for Raspberry Pi.

Here's why:

1. The official System Requirements lists Intel processors (or equivalent) as a requirement ([reference](https://ubuntustudio.org/download/#)).

   |  | Required: | Recommended: |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | **CPU:** | Intel Core 2 Duo equivalent | Intel Core i5 equivalent or better |
   | **RAM:** | 2GB | 8GB |
   | **Drive Space:** | 16GB | 64GB, more for audio/video work |
2. Ubuntu Studio might rely on the "low-latency" kernel variant (included in the installation image), which is by default not released for Raspberry Pi.

I'm not saying it's impossible to build Ubuntu Studio for Raspberry Pi, but I don't see it being available out of the box.

**However**, after digging through the packages, it actually looks like the packages for Ubuntu Studio are available on all platforms, including Arm64 (with reference to N0rbert's comment above).

This poses an interesting idea - is it in fact possible to install the Ubuntu Studio desktop and additional packages so they run on a Raspberry Pi?

First you need to enable Universe repositories. Make sure these lines are uncommented in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
```

You could then try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop^
```

And then install additional packages, according to your needs.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop^
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-fonts^
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-graphics^
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-photography^
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-publishing^
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-video^
```

However, referring to the official website this would be unsupported, and entirely on your own risk.

Refer to [this existing question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339086/66509), as pointed out by N0rbert, for details.