# I have a RasPi 4 8gb & want the Ubuntu Studio on it for the editing video tools. I am struggling big time to get this

Tags: software-installation

I have the Ras PI 4 8gb and I had KDE Plasma through Finuxlinux and liked it. I am knew to the Pi and the Linux. Not and expert in any of this. I saw that Ubuntu Studio has a lot of editing tools for making Youtube videos and such so I thought I would just switch to ubuntu. I cant get it to install from any option on the site? Is it a SD card corruption problem or what link is best to get this on my PI? It will not boot? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run Ubuntu Studio on a Raspberry pi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351959/can-i-run-ubuntu-studio-on-a-raspberry-pi). Also, from the developer's Facebook page: "[Ubuntu Studio targets fairly powerful machines, so the answer to your question is no, nor will there be in the future.](https://www.facebook.com/Ubuntustudio/photos/a.10151376037015622/10156413235355622/?type=3)"

Comment: I'm using the raspi4 with kodi, but cutting video does not make sense. Check [here](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut) for my very video fast cutter -  but it won't be that fast on your hardware, since it relies on cores - many of of them ;-)

Comment: I didn't know it wasn't strong enough to run editing. I am glad I asked and got these answers. Thank you all. I appreciate the help for sure.